# Google Places API - How to get next page of results in Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Web Service API with RestClient gem in my web app to look for businesses with certain string. For example, passing in 'car dealership' should returns the results of all car dealership near me.

Currently, I'm able to get the first page of results. Already passing in the next_page_token but stuck at getting the same results. Not sure where it went wrong in my code. Really appreciate the help!

```
    SEARCH_ENDPOINT = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json'.freeze
    DETAILS_ENDPOINT = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json'.freeze

    def initialize(query)
      @params = {
        query: query,
        fields: 'name,formatted_phone_number,formatted_address,website,place_id,types',
        key: API_KEY
      }
      @results = []
    end

    def extract
      loop do
        page_token = @results.last&.dig('next_page_token')

        page = fetch_page(page_token)
        break if page.nil?

        @results += page['results']

        break if page['next_page_token'].nil?

        # Add a delay to avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors (10 requests per second)
        sleep(10)
      end

      @results = @results.map do |result|
        result_details = fetch_place_details(result['place_id'])
        result.merge(result_details)
      end

      upsert_businesses(clean_data(@results))
    end

    private

    def fetch_page(page_token)
      response = RestClient.get(SEARCH_ENDPOINT, params: @params.merge({page_token: page_token}))

      return nil unless response.code == 200

      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    def fetch_place_details(place_id)
      response = RestClient.get(DETAILS_ENDPOINT, params: @params.merge({place_id: place_id}))

      return {} unless response.code == 200

      details = JSON.parse(response.body)['result']

      details || {}
    end
```

Passed in the next page token to the params, expecting a new page of response. But receiving the same results.

Comment: possible duplicate/related question: [Paging on Google Places API returns status INVALID_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265756/paging-on-google-places-api-returns-status-invalid-request)

Comment: I'm sorry but the link above is from 2014. The api documentation link is not showing what you quoted. But anyways I'm not getting INVALID_REQUEST response. I'm getting multiple pages with different next page token but all the pages are returning the same results as the first page.

Answer (score 0):

The following line was erasing the page_token every time:

```
page_token = @results.last&.dig('next_page_token')
```

Also, the correct syntax for the page_token param is `pagetoken` (at least in Ruby).